# can't access a member variable in struct array in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, member-variables

I am making a C program, which needs to access a struct array in a struct.

The definition looks like below

```
struct def_world
{
    bool lock;
    char tilemap;
    def_tile tile[100][100];
struct def_tile
{
    bool lock;
    char kind;
    def_obj * obj;
    void * evt;
};
struct def_obj
{
    bool lock;
    int indexOfTable;
    bool frozen;
    char x,y;
    char kind;
    char face;
    char * msg;
    char * ip;
};
```

in the main function, I want to access world's `tile[3][3]`'s obj's face.

I initialize world as

```
def_world world={0,};
```

but the following lines make errors

```
world.tile[3][3].obj=newobj();//newobj() returns def_obj type

world.tile[3][3].obj->face;
```

any idea how to access obj's face?

Comment: Show the at least the declaration for `newobj()` it's important to know whether it returns a `def_obj` object or a `def_obj*` pointer to a `def_obj`. Actually, why not post a compilable example that produces the errors that you get - it shouldn't be much more than what you have right now, but it will eliminate the need for people to guess about typos (please use copy-n-paste - don't retype it in the SO edit box).

Comment: Works fine for me using VS2010 (and reversing the declared order of structs). Also, this is C++ not C, there is no `bool` in C. Perhaps `newobj` is defined as `def_obj newobj ()` rather than `def_obj *newobj ()`?

Comment: the thing is that my VS2010 says No Members available when I just finished the typing world.tile[3][3] something wrong?

Comment: I solved the problem sorry;; the thing I confused is struct definition order. after change the order, it works nicely thanks Michael and Skizz

Comment: Even though you've got a solution, could you edit the question to show the actual declarations?  You have a missing `};` on the declaration of `struct def_world`, you're referring to types before they've been declared, and you're referring to `struct def_tile` as just `def_tile` (which is legal in C++ but not in C).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try these lines instead:</strike>

```
world.tile[3][3]->obj=newobj();//newobj() returns def_obj type

world.tile[3][3]->obj.face;
```

Explanation:
`world.tile[3][3]` is a `def_tile`. It's `obj` field isn't `def_obj`, but rather `def_obj*`. Therefore, to get the `def_obj` that it points to, you should use `->obj`.
Inside `def_obj`, face is just a char, so you would access it with `.face`.

Comment: -1 this is incorrect. You've got it backwards. The OP has it right.

Comment: @Chris: you're right of course. And its the 2nd time that this happens to me today =/

Comment: Don't worry, we all have brainfarts. I'll even refund your rep. ;)